# Cannot play wmv files inside movie player

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, wmv

I am on Ubuntu 10.10. I installed everything like win64codecs that is required to play restricted formats and tried everything to play a online wmv. I get this error in movie player:

```
vide0/x-asf-unknown decoder error.
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install [smplayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)? Other possibility is VLC player, but I prefer Smplayer. :-)

> SMPlayer intends to be a complete front-end for MPlayer, from basic features like playing videos, DVDs, and VCDs to more advanced features like support for MPlayer filters and more.

Comment: i am able to play some local files .. but i want to play wvx files that is hosted online